# Apache commands with 2nd instance on Mac OS X

Tags: apache, osx-mavericks, filemaker

I have a Mac OS X 10.9/Mavericks Mac which I have just installed FileMaker Server v13. The FileMaker Server installer creates its own instance of the Apache web server and configures this web server to use port 80 for HTTP and port 443 for HTTPS. The document root for this instance is located at:

/Library/FileMaker Server/HTTPServer/htdocs

I'm trying to use the Apache commands via the Mac OS X Terminal to stop/start/restart this instance but it looks like it's trying to use the standard OS X Apache not the FileMaker Server installed instance.

For example I would like to use:

```
sudo apachetctl restart
```

When there are 2 instances of Apache installed how do you specify which instance you wish to command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the answer. The following syntax will work:

sudo /Library/Filemaker\ Server/HTTPServer/bin/httpdctl graceful

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your OS Apache running it needs to be on a different port. FileMaker doesn't really support console commands and wants you to restart the computer to restart apache.

You can try with the launchctl:

`sudo launchctl stop com.filemaker.fms
sudo launchctl start com.filemaker.fms`

Or you can try to run httpd and specify the 2nd file directly

`/usr/sbin/httpd -f /Library/FileMaker\ Server/HTTPServer/conf/httpd.conf -t`

Answer (score -2):

if you you want to restart FileMaker Server you should use this commands in Terminal :

- **fmsadmin start server**
- **fmsadmin stop server**
- **fmsadmin restart server**

Comment: I'm wanting to restart Apache that's installed with FileMaker Server, not FileMaker Server itself.